# Is there a way to customize github columns in file list?

Tags: github

Right now, it shows:

- Filename
- Last commit message
- Last commit time

Is there a way to include other things, e.g. file size, or to reorder / sort columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can do it at Github. Maybe Enterprise Github allows that.

Comment: That's a shame... :( Out of curiosity, do you have any references?

Comment: references for what ??

Comment: References that there's no way to do it - any URLs confirming that?